# How to pass model data in a each loop in template to controller without using action in ember

Tags: ember.js

This is the template:

```
{{#each user in inquiry.users}}
    <li>
       {{user.email}}
       <div class="pretty small danger btn icon-right entypo icon-cancel" {{action 'removeUser' user}}><a href="#">remove</a></div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

This is the controller:

```
    App.ManageUsersModalController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['inquiry'],
    inquiry: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.inquiry.model'),

    createdBy: function() {
        return this.get('inquiry.created_by').substring(4);
    }.property('inquiry'),
    username: function(){
        return this.get('user.username');
    }.property(),

    //indented
});
```

I want to check whether the user is primary or not by compare the `inquiry.created_by` and `user.username`. I can get properties in the inquiry model. But can't do the same for user model. Can someone tell me how to pass the child data while do a loop in the template to controller without using action helper. As I don't need a click on the page to show whether the user is primary or not.

Comment: Why do you need to create such a structure: 'controller->inquiry->model->template->users->user->controller'? Could it be that you're looking for something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers?

Comment: Hi Microfed, the reason is that this is a old piece of code created by higher level team member and I have limited rights. But just as you and kristjan said, I can use a helper. Good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write an isEqual helper.

```
import Ember from "ember";

// http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select

export function checkEquality([leftSide, rightSide]) {
    return leftSide === rightSide;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(checkEquality);
```

hbs

```
{{#if (isEqual user.created_by inquiry.created_by)}}
     xxxx
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I feel surprised how could I didn't get this idea. Anyway, a lot of thanks!

Comment: @JieZhang Glad i was able to help.